# JS tests with Karma/Mocha/Chai/Gulp

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I've tried to add testing to my web app boilerplate which is held together with gulp.

I've added Karma/Mocha/Chai and I have execute the testing in Gulp watch:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'build-css'], () => {
    gulp.watch('./app/scss/**/*.scss', ['build-css']);
  gulp.watch(['app/*.html', 'app/js/**/*.js'], browserSync.reload);     //Also reloads the browser when HTML or JS changes                  
    gulp.watch(['app/js/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.test.js'], ['test']);      //Re-run tests whenever JS or test changes
});

gulp.task('test',                                                       //Run tests once
    shell.task('karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless karma.conf.js')
);
```

In my `karma.conf.js` I'm loading all my files:

```
files: [
  'app/*.html',
  'app/css/*.css',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/**/*.test.js'
],
```

Now, the actual test file works.  So if I have this:

**script.test.js**

```
describe('Array', () => {
    describe('#indexOf()', () => {
      it('should return -1 when the value is not present', () => {
        assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3,].indexOf(4));
      });
    });
  });
```

then I get a pass, no problem.
[image]

The problem I have is that my main script.js file is causing Karma to fall over. I believe it's because it's trying to manipulate the DOM.  I have a function called `createUI` which takes a couple of arguments, one of which is the ID of the page element the UI should be inserted into.  It works exactly as I want when it's being run normally, but when Karma runs a test it gives me this:

```
HeadlessChrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.2) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined\nat /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/app/js/script.js:10:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:11:43\n\nReferenceError: table is not defined\n    at Object.require./Users/jamesbrenton/Documents/webapp-boilerplate/app/js/script.js (/var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/app/js/script.js:10:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:11:43)\n    at s (/var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:1:273)\n    at app/js/script.js:1:34",
    "str": "Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined\nat /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/app/js/script.js:10:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:11:43\n\nReferenceError: table is not defined\n    at Object.require./Users/jamesbrenton/Documents/webapp-boilerplate/app/js/script.js (/var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/app/js/script.js:10:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:11:43)\n    at s (/var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:0 <- /var/folders/bb/v9p4j7395_9f24f49p04h1pr0000gq/T/195d5d9b0835bfdadaba24427f863496.browserify:1:273)\n    at app/js/script.js:1:34"
  }
```

If I wrap my function call inside a `window.onload` block like this:

**script.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    cards.createUI(deck, table);
};
```

then the tests appear to pass.  However, I cannot believe that this is the correct way of resolving this issue as the code works under normal circumstances. Can I delay Karma from starting tests until the DOM is loaded?  Or have I missed something here?